# How the windows-server-2012 support run the ".phtml" files

Tags: php, windows-server-2012, web-platform-installer

I am setting the windows server 2012 with the phtml, however, the server only support ".php" but not support the ".phtml" .

After I run the web-platform to install the php7,
The system can run the helloworld.php and it can display the result.
But when I created the index.phtml, and run visit the page, the browser would only download the new file, not open the website on the browser. 
Would I need to add the ".phtml" extension on the IIS? 
Where I can add the extension?

would I need to add the apache server to support running the ".phtml"
Or the IIS can add the extension type like 
"AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml"

both the index.php and the index.phtml only have the following code

Comment: both the index.php and the index.phtml only have the following code (1 line coding )

echo "hello world";

Comment: You should be able to configure the IIS-server to parse .phtml as php-files. No need for Apache. I don't know why since I don't usually use PHP under IIS.